# Using Ubuntu/Rackspace Server as an audio-stream

Tags: sound, internet-radio, stream

I'm looking for using a Ubuntu server as a streaming server for my webradio. I use this software called Nicecast to capture the audio produced on a local computer and redirect it to a server. The clients should then be able to connect to the stream via an URL (something .mp3).
Can't work it out for the moment, thus help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, Nicecast appears to be a pretty simple broadcast service with a built-in icecast server (or optional remote server setup).

If using built-in server:
(ie: on your local machine) the world will not be able to connect to your address, unless you set up port forwarding on your router.

If using a remote hosted icecast server:
Simply add the remote server's icecast URL:8000 to your broadcast list, and connect.

So, now that my assumptions are out of the way, where exactly are you having the issues Do you just need help installing and setting up Icecast on an Ubuntu server at Rackspace? (If so... if you give me a bit, I can assist much deeper when I get to my desk. I'm working from the house at the moment, and about to leave for the office.)